# I have a table where I created 5 columns level1,level2,level3,level4,level5 and I want to count the existence of value like 1 in particular columns..?

Tags: mysql

[I have a table where I created 5 columns level1,level2,level3,level4,level5 and I want to count the existence of value like 5 in particular columns..?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEX11.png)
Database Table

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @Diego V

Answer (score 0):

> You can make it like this.

Syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE `level1`='1';
```

**Output:** `2` as per your table structure.

Example as per your Request:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE `level1` = 1 OR `level2` = 1  OR `level3` = 1 OR `level4` = 1 OR `level5` = 1;
```

For more reference you can visit here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM levels WHERE level1 = 5 OR level2 = 5  OR level3 = 5 OR level4 = 5 OR level5 = 5
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13472338)

Comment: I am printing the  count of value 5 in the table

Comment: it is printing the values of all levels in single count as sum

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want this as a pivot table?

```
/*
drop table t;
create table t (id int,level1 int,level2 int,level3 int,level4 int,level5 int);
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(1,1,null,null,null,null), (2,null,1,null,null,null), (3,null,null,1,null,null),(4,null,null,null,1,null),
(5,null,null,null,null,1),(6,1,1,1,1,1);
*/

  SELECT 'Obs>>' as 'LevelCounts',
            LEVEL1,LEVEL2,LEVEL3,LEVEL4,LEVEL5,
            LEVEL1+LEVEL2+LEVEL3+LEVEL4+LEVEL5 Total
from
(
    select
     sum(case when level1 = 1 then 1 end) level1,
    sum(case when level2 = 1 then 1 end) level2,
    sum(case when level3 = 1 then 1 end) level3,
    sum(case when level4 = 1 then 1 end) level4,
    sum(case when level5 = 1 then 1 end) level5
from    t
) s
```

Result

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| LevelCounts | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | LEVEL4 | LEVEL5 | Total |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Obs>>       |      2 |      2 |      2 |      2 |      2 |    10 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```